# scrartcl margins, font size and more

Tags: koma-script

I'm asked to do a project in A4 format, 12 pt and with margins of 2.5 cm each.

I usually work with scrartcl with default settings I don't how to start ( specially with the margins)

Moreover, I want to add my personal information in the first page without making a title page. Is there any option to to do this?

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
 \usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{authblk}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}} 
\newtheorem{lema}{Lema}
\newtheorem{definicion}{Definición}
\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}
\newcommand{\B}{\bigskip}
```

Comment: For the margins, load the geometry package

Comment: I did this: \usepackage[a4paper, margin={2.5cm]{geometry} but this only affects the left margin

Comment: That should do the trick for the margins: `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}`

Is there any particular reason to not use a titlepage?

Comment: Thanks! But to me , left margin seems a bit wider. :/

Comment: Well I'm asked to do a small report  and the title should be something small not as big as the usual titlepage.

Comment: Without more information, we cannot tell why you see different margins. It is possible that later package `typeare` takes over again. Impossible to say without a MWE.

Comment: I edited my post with all the preamble I hope it helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the obsolete package `anysizes` that also sets the margins.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm
  %,showframe% <- only to show the page layout
]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{anysize}% <- remove this package
\usepackage{dsfont}
%\usepackage{graphicx}% 
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz, graphicx, xcolor
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}% use all possibilities of the current version 1.12
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{underscore}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{authblk}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}} 
\newtheorem{lema}{Lema}
\newtheorem{definicion}{Definición}
\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}
\newcommand{\B}{\bigskip}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\author{My name}
\title{Title}
\maketitle
\section{Section One}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```